# PHP Driver: If I KIll a PHP process will it also kill SQL Server Process (query)?

Tags: php, sql-server

I am using PHP SQL Server driver - is there a way to kill the last query sent by `sqlsrv_query` function?

If not, if I kill the PHP process will it also kill the query in turn?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you specify "kill the query"? Abort a currently running query? That's probably not possible. Undo the last executed query? That's certainly not possible. What do you want to do?

Comment: I want to be able to abort a currently running query. This is possible in SQL Server Management studio (Kill Process) - I am guessing I can do this via PHP Driver for SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do this.

Take a look at [MySQL's kill command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/kill.html), that should help you with what query to use.

When do you want to invoke it? If its inline with your PHP, then just write up a query and execute it. If you want to do it if the page is closed, you may want to consider setting up a second PHP page that runs the command, and then hitting it with AJAX with JavaScript's event for closing pages.

Comment if you have any questions

Comment: Thanks but I was hoping the same for SQL Server using a function call from the PHP Module Driver for SQL Server.

Comment: Ooh sorry - didn't notice it was SQL Server. Why do it from a module driver if you can just use a SQL query? All a function in the module would do is call this query